# Source code editor for Windows with a feature like Embedded terminal on Gedit

Tags: editor, command, notepad++, prompt, gedit

I am looking for Notepad++-like source code editor with 
built-in Command prompt. I did not like **NppExec** plugin for Notepad++ because it uses its own scripting language.

I am looking for something like **Embedded Terminal** feature in Gedit on Linux.

There is a version of Gedit for Windows; however, this version doesn't have Embedded Terminal plugin or anything like this.

Comment: You could run gedit with cygwin (in theory) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), it has a built-in terminal and lots of useful plugins.
The downside (for some) is that it's Java based, but it's very responsive and can be made to look rather native.